# For REST resources that do not exist, when to return 404 and when to return 403?

Tags: rest

I am familiar with the logic, that if you wish to authenticate someone with username and password, you should return the same error, no matter if the username is not found, or if the password is wrong. The idea being, that if you returned separate "user not found" and "user found, but password wrong" errors, an attacker could at try all usernames and at find out which usernames are valid, then concentrate their dictionary attacks only on those usernames.

With a REST service, I have a resource which only certain users can access, let's call it `/foo/{id}`. So there are various cases:

1. A user attempts to access `/foo/4` and they have access, they obviously get a 200 response and the resource.
2. A user attempts to access `/foo/3` and it doesn't exist. (I cannot tell if they would have had access to it if it did exist, as it doesn't exist. Think a non-existent photo on Facebook, a photo only has ownership information when it exists.)
3. A user attempts to access `/foo/4`, it exists, but they do not have access.

So my question is, what return codes to return in case 2 and 3? As far as I can see there are the options:

1. Return 404 for case 2, and 403 for case 3. But that means an attacker can find out which objects exist, similar to the password example in the first example.
2. Return 404 for all examples, after all, from the perspective of the user, the resource they don't have access to "doesn't exist", if they list all the resources they have access to that resource will not be in the list.
3. Return 403 for all examples.

What would you do? What is the standard here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the standard here?

[HTTP Semantics 15.5.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.5.4)

> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of 404 (Not Found).

Interestingly enough, in [HTTP/1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-9.4), this was turned around

> If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (forbidden) can be used instead.

You should be aware that 403 and 404 have [different default caching behavior](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.1).

[OWASP: Exception Handling](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Exception_Handling#HTTP_Status_Codes)

> When reviewing error responses be careful that a malicious user is not able to glean any potentially sensitive information about the system from the status code returned. For example: an API search that takes a tenant ID parameter and returns an HTTP 404 response for no results, and an HTTP 500 response if the tenant ID does not exist. An attacker could potentially leverage this information to determine if a tenant ID is valid or not. One solution would be to catch the exception thrown when a supplied tenant ID does not exist, and return an HTTP 404 status code with the error response.

Note that the status code is not the only part of the response that can be exploited; if you are going to go through the effort of aligning the status code, you should also make sure that the message-body and the headers don't give anything away either, that [the timing of the response](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2015/07/26/account-enumeration-via-timing-attacks/) doesn't give the show away, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

On our project we proceed with option one:

`404` - if resource physically is missing

`403` - if user has no rights to access

The problem with id-guessing was solved by using an opaque identifiers, like `GUIDs`:

```
/foo/08490cee-c5a1-4ea5-a00e-1a488fd58044
```

Unguessable identifiers are common recommendation for any public API, because  otherwise an attacker can simply add or subtract ID numbers or even learn things they shouldn't know such as how many entity objects have been created. Also remember - database primary key may still be integer.

Other than that I'm not sure there would be any standard here. You may proceed with any of three that works for you business domain.

Answer (score 0):

If the resource has an owner, or multiple owners, this might help:

If the resource does indeed exist, but the user should not be allowed to see it, internally think of it like "resource does exist - but not for you!", therefore I'd return 404.

As you said, be careful where you return 403 as it may expose internal meta data.